# Question about version numbers and in app purchases?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am finishing up an app for a client that uses in app purchases and i am getting ready to create the app in itunes connect so i can add products.

My question is do i have to enter in all the final info such as name, description, icons, screenshots, version, etc.., that i will be using to release the app with or can i just create a stub app and modify the info once i have all the in app purchase stuff working correctly??

The other idea i had was to just create version .5 or something to test with and then create version 1.0 with all the final metadata? Can you do that without uploading a binary and going through the review process?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of an answer from a question I had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780440/i-cannot-get-in-app-purchase-test-to-work). I think it may address your needs for testing in app purchase:

```
* Your app does not need to be live in the store.
* You do need an app in the App store submission. Reject the binary after uploading it.
* Testing your app should work in Release or Debug modes
* You do need an in app product "Cleared for sale"
* Your product request only needs to contain the product id(s)
```

The version number is immaterial as it wont matter until the app is released. Therefore you may use 1.0 and it may remain 1.0 because the version number won't be used until approved and in the iTunes App store.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The version number is *not* immaterial: I don't think it's possible to change it once you've submitted a binary (at least, it didn't let me change the version number of an update in the past).

Comment: Correct. I should have written that differently. My intended meaning is that he does not need to use .5 while testing. He could use 1.0 while testing and it can remain 1.0 when he does the actual release.